# Bourne shell script that tests for a file and creates it if not found

Tags: shell

need a script to test if a file exists and output "file found" if it exists, or "file not found" if it doesn't exist and then create the file.  can this be done with a positional parameter as well?  thanks!

## !/bin/sh

if find file
then
echo "file found"
else
echo "file not found" && touch file
fi

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your questions regarding `/bin/sh` you can easily modify the above to:

```
filenm=/path/to/file/to/check.txt
if [ -f "$filenm" ] ; then
    printf "file exists\n"
else
    printf "file does not exist -- creating\n"
    touch "$filenm"
fi
```

You can also replace the `single-bracket test` above `[ stuff ]` with `test -f "$filenm"` (leave a space between the closing quote and semi-colon (e.g. `if test -f "$filenm" ; then`). You can also accomplish the same with a compound command. (using `test` but you can substitute `[ ]` as well:

```
test -f "$filenm" && printf "file exists" || { printf "file does not exist\n"; touch "$filenm"; }
```

After you test and create a file, it is good practice to verify it has been created:

```
test -f "$filenm" || touch "$filenm"
test -f "$filenm" || { printf "error, unable to create %s\n" "$filenm"; exit 1; }
```

Comment: hello - if i didnt know where the path was and i just needed to search for the filename in all directories would the filnm= /  ?

Comment: Yes, that would cause find to search the entire drive. However, you are better off limiting it to `/home`, `/usr`, `/var` (and perhaps your web-server document root. **Avoid searching** `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ -e /path/to/file ]]; then
    echo "File found!"
else
    echo "File not found! Creating it"
    touch /path/to/file
fi
```

Take a look at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html too.